# Suppress title of apa7 document to be set as the first section

Tags: apa7

I'm currently trying to submit a manuscript in psychology. For this, I use the apa7 document class. However, the journal requires section numbering as well as "Introduction" to be the first section.

1. I know that I can enable section numbering by writing `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` after the `\maketitle` command
2. But I don't know how to suppress the fact that when using `make title` I  get my manuscript title as the first header when the document starts.

Here is what I have got so far:

```
%% SETTINGS
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
\usepackage[american]{babel}


%% Title page information
\title{GGG}
\shorttitle{GGGG}

\authorsnames[1,2,1]{One name , scecond name, third name}
\authorsaffiliations{{asdas} ,
                     {basdsad}}


\authornote{\flushleft \vspace{-1.5cm}
\addORCIDlink{blub}{0000-0000-000}
\qquad Correspondence concerning this article should be addressed .....}

%% Abstract page
\abstract{an abstract}

\keywords{BLI, BLA, BLUB}


%% Main document: Start

\begin{document}
\maketitle
% Modifications necessary for Journal 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\section{Introduction}


\end{document}
```

[image: This is what I want to disappear :)]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: One of the (many) design choices of the `apa7` document class is that the document's "main" title, contained in the argument of `\title`, is shown on both the title page and the first page *after* the abstract page. I wouldn't say that the repeated title amounts to a second section-level header.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the comment. I thought it is treated as a section because when I switch `\maketitle` and `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`, the title receives a number. Is there a way I can change the design choices easily?

Comment: You wrote, "when I switch \maketitle and \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}, the title receives a number." That's not what I'm getting when I run your code: The title has no number, as it should be.

Comment: okay, interesting. Because honestly I do (currently using overleaf).

Comment: We seem to be talking past one another: The screenshot you posted does *not* show a number associated with the title ("GGG"), but it does show the correct number -- "1" -- associated with the first sectioning header -- "Introduction".

Comment: Yes, your right, and thank you for still be willing to help :). Yes, the post does not show a number associated with the title. I simply said that it does, however, when I switch `maketitle` and `setcounter`... Anyway, that is not the main problem. I mainly want to suppress the fact that the title ("GGG") is shown on the first page after the abstract page ... '1 Introduction' shall be the only thing on that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apa7` document class provides the option `donotrepeattitle`, which -- I think you can already guess what it does... -- tells LaTeX not to repeat the paper's title.

Thus, you need to change

```
\documentclass[man]{apa7}
```

to

```
\documentclass[man,donotrepeattitle]{apa7}
```

in order to achieve your formatting objective.

For more information about the options recognized by the `apa7` document class, please see pages 3 and 4 of the class's [user guide](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/apa7/apa7.pdf).

By the way, the user guide also says that `\maketitle` should be the very first instruction after `\begin{document}`; see page 7 of the user guide.